# Borel ideals on $\omega$ are meager?

Tags: descriptive-set-theory

Let $\mathcal{I}$ be a proper [ideal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_%28set_theory%29) on $\omega$. If $\mathcal{I}$ is Borel as a subset of $2^\omega$, does it follow that $\mathcal{I}$ is meager?

**Edit:** What if $\mathcal{I}$ contains all finite subsets of $\omega$?

Comment: All sets not containing $0$ ... that's an ideal, right?  And Borel.  In fact clopen.  So not meager.

Comment: Right. What if we assume that all finite subsets are in $\mathcal{I}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us consider a prime ideal J containing I. Suppose I is non meager. Then J would have non empty interior (modulo meager). Since complementing a set of integers is a meager preserving operation so the dual ultrafilter U of J has the same property. But both J and U are closed under rational translations and they both have interiors (modulo meager) so they are both comeager which is impossible.

Comment: Much as I like ultrafilters, I have to point out that they're not really needed here. If I is a proper, non-meager, Borel ideal that contains the finite sets, and if F is the dual filter, then, being closed under finite modifications (a.k.a. rational translations), both I and F are comeager, which is absurd because they are disjoint.

Comment: Hi. I'm new to descriptive set theory, so could you use layman's language? I don't understand the terms "prime ideal", "modulo meager", and "rational translations".

Comment: After googling, I found what "rational translations" means. But, Andreas how does that imply that $I$ and $F$ are comeager? Where did you use the fact that $I$ is Borel?

Comment: @jack: The assumption that I and therefore F are Borel is used to ensure that they have the Baire property, which in turn implies that, if they're non-meager, then they are comeager in some open sets. That plus closure under finite modifications makes them comeager in all of $2^\omega$.

Comment: I see. Why is $F$ non-meager?

Comment: You are right. No need to extend the ideal.

Comment: I think I got it now. After all, $F$ is obtained from $I$ by taking complements, which means flipping 0s and 1s. This clearly preserves comeagerness. Thanks a lot guys!